How to model this constraint in a better way?
I have a resource allocation problem. There are $M$ users and $N$ resources (machines).
One user can be assigned to multiple resources/machines.
But maximum $B$ machines can be activated at a time for all the users.
The assignment variable (binary) vector is defined as $x$, $x$ is of length $M*N$
$x_1$: {user 1, machine 1}
$x_2$: {user 1, machine 2}
.
.
.
$x_N$: {user 1, machine $N$}
$x_{N+1}$: {user 2, machine 1}
$x_{N+2}$: {user 2, machine 2}
.
.
.
$x_{2*N}$: {user 2, machine $N$}
.
.
.
$x_{M*N}$: {user $M$, machine $N$}
I have modeled the constraint as
$L0$ norm of $(Ux)<=B$
where $U$ is a matrix carefully designed based on how $x$ is arranged
$U$ has $N$ rows and $M*N$ columns.
1's in each row correspond to the positions of differents users paired with the given resource.
I want to get a better model for this constraint without $L0$ norm. We can linearize $L0$ norm but in that case I need to introduce new variables and constraints which I don't want.
I can also a follow a different approach as mentioned in How to linearize this L0 norm of a vector?, but that will introduce a large number of constraints as U and R are vary large numbers, e.e., $M=100$, $N=100$; $B=5$;
Is there a better/easier modeling?

@Kuifje can you provide me some more details? This constraint is part of a problem. There are other constraints also.

I think it would help if you described in detail the whole problem. For example, is the trivial solution "0 users allocated to 0 machines" feasible?

@KGM, why do you actually want to use a $L-norm$ to restrict the required resources? Why not try to minimize e.g. the number of required or idle resources as the objective function? Also, this link may be relevant.

When you say $x$ is of length $UR,$ do you mean $MN?$

Have you considered a mixed integer linear program with binary variables to indicate which machines are in use?

@prubin it was a typo! Corrected

@prubin yes I tried. To transform into MILP I had to introduce new variables to linearize the multiplicative terms of binary variable. That added a lot of variables and constraints. Then introduced another set of variable to indicate which machines are in use and then used big-M method for linearization. This approach further adds new constraints!

The vector $Ux$ is $N\times 1,$ so you need $N$ binary variables and $N$ additional constraints to linearize the norm constraint.

@prubin yes, I did it. Actually my motivation is not using any solver. What do you think about gradient descent? The projection can also be done heuristically at each iteration, right?

I don't know what you mean.

@prubin I mean the most commonly used optimization algorithm in QP, as well as in many other large-scale optimization problems is gradient descent. Since I have a constrained QP, in each iteration/update, projection of the variable over the constrained search space is needed.

The $L_0$ norm is not quadratic. How is this a QP?

@prubin but I have $x^TQx+c^Tx$ as my objective.

Why don't you define the follwing variables
$x_{ij}:=\{0,1\}$ if user i assigned to machine j
to use these constraints,
$\sum_j x_{ij}\geq 1$   for each user i
at least one machine assigned to each user i
$\sum_i x_{ij}\leq 1$   for each machine j
at most one user assigned to each machine j
$\sum_{i,j} x_{ij}\leq B$
at most B machines are activated
But, if it possible to assigne a machine to more than one user, then, define the following variables
$y_{j}:=\{0,1\}$ if machine j is activated
to use these constraints,
$\sum_j x_{ij}\geq 1$   for each user i
at least one machine assigned to each user i
$M.y_j\geq \sum_i x_{ij}$   for each machine j
Only activated machine j can assigned to some users
$y_j\leq \sum_i x_{ij}$   for each machine j
If machine j does not assigned to some users then it is not activated
$\sum_j y_j \leq B$
at most B machines are activated

The constraint that an unused machine cannot be activated, while correct, is unnecessary. An activated but unused machine can just be ignored.

@prubin Yes. We can ignore it.
